# Identity Management - securing a REST API / web service

Tags: c#, .net, rest, security, identity-management

What are the practices in 2015 in the companies you work in to provide the highest security level when designing a REST API / web service?

Please answer taking into account **Identity Management**.

For example - do you still use hashes for passwords in your databases? I am sure many of you work in companies where the security level is of a great importance. I would be extremely grateful if you could share your current experience.

If it matters, we would like to use .NET 5 with their newest Web Api.

**EDIT**
Opinion based? I am asking for what people use to secure their services nowadays, there is nothing to be opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to avoid doing your own identity management all together. For applications used within your company, use your Active Directory ([ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx)) or cloud based directory ([Azure AD](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/)).

For all other (internet) applications, use a social identity provider like [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3), [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) or [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth).

Your users don't need another username and password to remember and you don't need the headaches of storing passwords and doing password resets.

Comment: "I think" = your opinion.

Comment: @spender I removed 'I think'. Is it a fact now? ;)

Comment: It's still really an opinion. What about the users [who don't want to use social logins](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295139/i-deleted-the-facebook-account-connected-to-my-stack-overflow-account-are-there?cb=1)?